# Cannot insert into local database

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to do a simple insert into a table with values from a windows form, but even using the debugger and checking step by step no errors seem to appear and the insert fails.

I did notice in the server explorer that as soon as I launch the debugger the connection is show and closed. The connection string I am getting as:

```
 SqlConnection con  = new SqlConnection(UI.Properties.Settings.Default.PM_ConnectionString);
```

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    public void agregarLocal(String _nombre, String _telefono, int _preferencia, int _provincia, String _url, SqlConnection _con, String _descripcion = "")
    {

        using (_con)
        {

            _con.Open();

            try
            {


                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(

                "INSERT INTO Locales VALUES(@loc_nombre, @loc_telefono, @loc_descripcion, @loc_preferencia, @loc_provincia, @loc_url)", _con))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_nombre", _nombre));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_telefono", _telefono));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_descripcion", _descripcion));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_preferencia", _preferencia));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_provincia", _provincia));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_url", _url));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    _con.Close();
            }


        }
```

The could not insert catch hasn't been showing as I said earlier. Any tip on something I may be missing?

EDIT: Added the changes suggested, the connection stills seems to be closed while the whole process is happening the PMDatabase still shows the red x.

Also I found a warning I overlooked, even though it doesn't seem relevant to the process of inserting into database here it is: warning MSB3270: `There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "WebKitBrowser, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `@` symbol in your SQL parameter names:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_nombre", _nombre));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_telefono", _telefono));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_descripcion", _descripcion));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_preferencia", _preferencia));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_provincia", _provincia));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc_url", _url));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: added the changes, but now it shows A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Count not insert.

Comment: Each time I run a test or try to use the adding function the connection to the database is closed. Is there any way besides stored procedures? In some way I think the problem may be with the conection string, as I am using a dataset to get some data to fill some comboboxs and those are working perfectly.